# STIntersects in the wrong lat/lng

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I'm facing a problem regarding the order of the lat/lng in the following query, it works if i put the coordinates in the wrong order (lng,lat). However geography::Point should take the lat then lng, this is very weird. I tried checking the lat/lng on google maps, and its in the correct position, the polygone in a clockwise order, everything looks fine, the query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @branch_id int = 0;
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::Point(31.3353608924066, 30.0798141318826,  4326);

SELECT B.ID, B.DeliveryZone, A.LatLong 
FROM [dbo].[Branches] AS B
INNER JOIN [dbo].Addresses AS A ON B.AddressID = A.ID 
WHERE   B.ServiceProviderID = 2 AND
        B.Deleted = 0  AND
        B.DeliveryZone.STBuffer(1000).STIntersects( @point ) > 0 ;
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your geospatial data in the Branches table is in (long, lat) order?

Comment: I've found the LAT/LON from google maps is in the wrong order from other spatial applications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQL Server documentation for Point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx) is inconsistent.   It says:

*Lat - Is a float expression representing the x-coordinate of the Point being generated.*

Latitude is generally used as a y-coordinate, that is, how far north or south you are from the equator.

The same inconsistency is given for Long:

*Long - Is a float expression representing the y-coordinate of the Point being generated.*

Of course, longitude is usually intepreted as an x-coordinate, that is, how far east or west you are from the prime meridian.

Also, lat and lng aren't used by all SRIDs, just ones that define unprojected coordinate systems like 4326, so "Lat" and "Long" are poor choices for generic parameter names in the documentation.

Based on these issues in the docs, it's most likely that for EPSG 4326, the database expects coordinates in `(x,y)` order, so `(lng, lat)`, **not** `(lat, lng)`.   This also is consistent with the way most other spatial systems define coordinates in EPSG 4326.